# How do I get off the boat?

Tags: mirrors-edge

I burst out of this van in *Mirror's Edge* and I have to take down 4 men with automatic guns straight away, with only my girly fists, of course! After the 10 or so attempts it takes me to kill these guys, I then get another wave of them.

There must be an easier way to do this level. I have searched around and can't see an exit.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with most places in *Mirror's Edge*, you shouldn't be sticking around to just kill or incapacitate bad guys and can generally just avoid them all.

After leaving the van, shift over to the left and down the side to the other garage area (where all the bad guys are).  In the back left corner, there are two trucks that you can use to get up.  The quick route would be to 1) wallrun, 2) jump to pipe, 3) jump to duct, 4) jump back to upper duct.  Easier is to just go up the pipe.

If you can't do it extremely fluidly, the guys with guns will rip you up, so if you can take out a few of them, it will be much easier.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do I do once I get up there? I can't see a way out

Comment: @tm1rbrt once you're on the vent, you keep walking in the ceiling then hang a right, getting to the next floor.